# Discrete mathematics equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have two sets A and B:

$$A = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 - 2x -3 < 0 \rbrace$$
$$B = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 < x < 3 \rbrace$$

I need to prove that A = B.

Thus I need to prove that $$ A \subseteq B$$
and $$ A \supseteq B$$

This is what I have so far:

Suppose x is an element of the real numbers such that $$ x^2 - 2x -3 < 0$$

We can factor to get

$$(x+1)(x-3)<0$$
Thus, either $$(x+1) < 0$$
or 
$$(x-3)<0$$

I can see that I get x<3 which is a property of the set B, but I don't understand what to do with the (x+1)<0.

Any hints?

---

EDIT: I've evaluated $$A \subseteq B$$ but I have no idea how to prove the opposite direction.

I know that based on the definition of B: 
$$ -1 < x < 3$$

My thoughts on approaching this problem is to look at the maximum and minimum values of x (i.e. 3 and -1 respectively) and to plug them into the definition of A: 
$$ x^2 - 2x - 3 < 0$$

And thus proving that the boundaries of x lie in set A.

Is this correct or is there a different/better way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create a sign chart to work with the quadratic equation. Either one of them is negative and the other positive or the opposite. BOTH being negative means the total thing is positive.

Comment: Thanks. I've evaluated the first part. I edited my post which includes my thoughts on the second part. Could you check if my thought process is correct?

Comment: Well, if you plug in the boundaries into the quadratic, you'll notice it becomes zero (since they are the roots) but note that you just want the quadratic to be LESS THAN zero, NOT zero. If I were you, I would simply say that $x^2-2x-3<0$ implies that $-1<x<3$, and therefore $A= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2-2x-3<0 \Rightarrow -1<x<3\} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: -1<x<3 \}$ which is by definition $B$. Therefore $A=B$. I hope I haven't confused you. :)

Comment: The only problem is that in order to prove the equality that A = B I need to prove both A is a subset of B and B is a subset of A. However saying that A implies -1 < x < 3 is just showing that A is a subset of B, correct?

Comment: Yes it does imply that but it ALSO implies that $B \subseteq A$ because all the real numbers in $B$ are also contained in $A$. So in a way, it's almost trivial to show that $B$ is a subset of $A$. But there you have it anyway.

Comment: And just for the sake of it, there is symmetry between the two sets so there's no real for $A$ to be a subset of $B$ and not the opposite. And also they are both shown to be defined in exactly the same way, so they have to be the same sets.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x+1)(x-3)<0$ if and only if exactly one of the factors is negative. So, $x-3<0$ and $x+1>0$, or $x+1<0$ and $x-3>0$

The first condition gives: $-1<x<3$.

Also, note that the second condition can't hold: $x>3$ and $x<-1$ is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order for $(x+1)(x-3)<0$ we have two cases:

**Case 1:** $x+1<0$ AND $x-3>0$ which implies $x<-1$ as well as $x>3$ which is impossible

**Case 2:** $x+1>0$ AND $x-3<0$ which implies $-1<x<3$ as we want it to be